# Find files that i added to an bootable USB

Tags: linux, boot, script, arch-linux

I used ISO Master to add a file to an Arch Linux installation .iso. But i can't find it. Where can i find the .sh file i added when i boot the .iso say on a VM? I have read many tutorials about making a custom bootable iso but nobody says where the folder/file can be find after i boot it... Maybe it has been right in my face the hole time and this is a stupid question but nevertheless i can't find it...
[what i did:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu7yQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the simplest is to mount the ISO drive

```
mkdir my-drive
sudo mount -o loop -t ext4 -r mydrive-iso.iso my-drive
```

If you didn't use `ext4` you may want to change that parameter. You should not actually need the `-t` unless you use an obscure file system.

Once mounted, you can try a command such as:

```
find my-drive -name '*.sh'
```

If that doesn't return your script then it's not there, somehow.

Comment: it shows the .sh file in the .iso next to the arch, EFI, isolinux,loader,shellx64.efi stuff. But when i boot the .iso, i can't find it anymore

Comment: Once booted up, can you see the other files? If not, then it probably doesn't mount the ISO filesystem at that level. You may have to move the .sh in a sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the file on the usb. It was in

```
/run/archiso/bootmnt/
```

The find command above hellped me find it this time, i don'y know why it did not show the firist time.

```
find my-drive -name '*.sh'
```